# how to get positon of the selected/clicked rating bar in a list of rating bars

Tags: android, listener, adapter, ratingbar

How can I get positon of the selected rating bar in a list of rating bars inside rating bar listener which is in a recyclerview adapter as shown in below code?
I am able to get the individual ratings of each rating bar when the user clicks it but I cant tell which rating bar the user I have clicked since there is no method of getting position of a particular rating bar in a list. I have placed the rating bar inside an adapter which populates the list in the recycler view as shown in the code below. I am using [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjymfOg6YPMAhVMuhoKHafWAyQQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftechery%2FProperRatingBar&usg=AFQjCNH61mIQ0ifkxk8iT0KABU-XpusUlQ&sig2=HO5dUGpPVvX4bbhCqUV4PA) library for the rating bar. and here is my code of the adapter where i have placed my listener, how can i get the position of the rating bar the user has selected inside my rating bar listener

```
    @Override
    public RateMa3Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
//        create a new view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rate, viewGroup, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(RateMa3.myOnClickListener);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        rootView = view;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        lowerRatingBar.setListener(ratingListener);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    private RatingListener ratingListener = new RatingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatePicked(ProperRatingBar ratingBar) {

            Snackbar.make(rootView,
                    String.format("Rating is %d " , ratingBar.getRating()),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("Rate", ratingBar.getRating() + "  rating");

// HOW CAN I GET THE POSITION OF A RATING BAR THE USER HAS CLICKED IN HERE?? THATS MY QUESTION, SINCE I HAVE A LIST OF RATING BARS
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only code that should be in the `onCreateViewHolder` method should be:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rate, viewGroup, false);
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
return viewHolder;
```

You should set the `onClickListener` in the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)` method. There you can use the second parameter, which is the position in the `RecyclerView`

To set the `onClickListener` to the whole view, use `viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener()`